# Difference between Azure Data Science VM and Azure Deep Learning VM

Tags: azure, azure-dsvm

I have been looking into Azure VMs for machine learning. The standard [Azure DSVM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/data-science-virtual-machines/) is a nice and easy solution for this. I also came across the [Azure Deep Learning VM](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-ca/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.dsvm-deep-learning), which is preconfigured to be used as a GPU-based DSVM. However, I can also deploy the standard DSVM as a GPU-based VM.

What is the difference between these two VMs?

Is it worth the hassle of deploying the Deep Learning VM, since this one can only be deployed in its own Resource Group and Virtual Network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much difference between these two in terms of tools and frameworks. The deep learning VM has few extra samples on deep learning and the deployment has been targeted for the GPU based VMs.

You are correct on this "I can also deploy the standard DSVM as a GPU-based VM." So if you don't care about those few samples, you are good with DSVM. Soon we are going to deprecate Azure Deep Learning VM and keep only "DSVM".